# How can i writing test bench for multiple module?

Tags: verilog, test-bench

I am new in this field,
I don't know if they've been asked before.
I'm writing code by creating separate modules to get used to big projects. 
I have no problems creating modules, but I don't know how to create a testbench.So I should write test bench according to main module.
but the main module was created with reference to 3 separate modules. 
How should be testbench of the following code?
Can you help me with this code?

```
//location of the main program

module circuit1_main(A,sel_m,Q);

input [2:0]A;
input sel_m;
output Q;
wire clk_m,reset_m,ud_m,load_m;

wire [2:0]A;
wire sel_m;
wire Q;

wire internal1;
wire internal2;
wire internal3;
wire internal4;

circuit1_counter cnt1(.clk(clk_m),.reset(reset_m),
                 .en(1'b1),.ud(ud_m),.load(load_m),
                      .d(A),.cnt(internal1));

assign internal2 = ~internal1;


circuit1_mux mux1(.a(internal1),.b(internal2),
                  .sel(sel_m),.out(internal3));


circuit1_shiftreg shiftreg1(.clk(clk_m),.reset(reset_m),
                            .sin(internal3),.sout(internal4));

assign Q = internal4;

endmodule
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have some bad new for you: You can't really write a test-bench for your 'circuit1_main' as it is rather broken.

Your module has a number of internal signals: `clk_m,reset_m,ud_m,load_m;` which should all come from outside. They should all be input ports which you must drive from your test bench.

I suspect, from the usage of the name 'main' that you are more comfortable with using C, C++ or other standard  programming language. It is very important to realise that writing HDL is rather different. I therefore suggest you have a look around at some existing HDL code.
I know that the internet is full of HDL examples of FIFOs, UARTS, Counters etc., but that test benches are few and far between, [Here](https://www.verilog.pro/) is one which has code **and** the test benches that come with them.

I would also suggest you do not split your code into modules which are very, very small:   Your `circuit1_mux` would be one line of code: `assign out = sel ? a : b ;`<sup>1</sup>  Writing a module and connecting it up is ten times more work then using that single line of code and less confusing. Is `out` equal to `a` or to `b` when `sel_m` is high?

<sup>1</sup><sub>Substituting your port name could make it `assign internal3 = sel_m ? internal1 : internal2; which make immediately clear to anybody that sel_m selects the internal1 case.</sub>